# How to check for matching data and accumulate if match is true?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Hello I currently have this data listed as
CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, gender, amount spent

```
REDACTED
```

How would I loop through this datafile in awk, and check for matching customerids $1 then if found a match add the purchased numbers up?

my best guess is something along the lines of checking the previous LINE with the next line and doing mini comparisons but that feels slow especially with a large amount of data, and also I dont understand how to do that.

```
awk 'BEGIN {

if (array[$0] == array[$1])
   #match
   #combine the two and add the purchase {print sum+=$5}
}
else
{print}
}' < infile > outfile
```

expected output

```
REDACTED
```

Comment: My first thoughts: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), [Falsehoods programmers believe about gender](https://gist.github.com/garbados/f82604ea639e0e47bf44) => https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood

Comment: Is the input already sorted?

Comment: @glennjackman yes the input has already been sorted by customer-id

Comment: We have redacted your example data as it looked like it contained personal information. Please update your question with fake data instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
   { $5=sum[$1]+=$5; customer[$1]=$0 }
END{ for (c in customer) print customer[c] }' infile
```